# Finding the value of $x$ if $\ln(x)+\ln(e)=\ln(18)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\ln(x)+\ln(e)=\ln(18)$

The first step I did was making $\ln(e)=1 $ and then bring $\ln(x) $ to the other side of the equation.

> $1=\ln(18) -\ln(x) $
>
> $1=\ln(18 - x) $

Then I raise the numbers to be exponents of $e$, but I believe perhaps there is a different way, or I'm doing the incorrect way, because the problem should be used without a calculator, according to my teacher. But here are the following steps I did:

> $e^1=(18-x) $
>
> $x=18+e $

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: First, notice that $\ln(a) + \ln(b) = \ln(ab) \neq \ln(a + b)$.

Comment: $\ln(a)-\ln(b)\neq \ln(a-b)$ Know the rules: $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$ and $\ln(a)-\ln(b)= \ln(\frac{a}{b})$

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes more sense. Now I see I was just confused. So, $\ 1=ln(18/x) $ is the first step, and the answer would then be $\ x=18/e $? Thank you for your comment, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

No, $18+e$ is clearly wrong (perhaps, there could theoretically be more than one correct answer, but in fact, there *is* only one correct answer, as I will show now). If $\operatorname{ln}(x)+\operatorname{ln}(e)=\operatorname{ln}(18)$, then applying $e^x$ to both sides gives $xe=18$, so $x=\frac{18}{e} \neq 18+e$. There is no other correct solution for $x$.

Comment: -1 Stating the answer and showing it works when you plug it in does not show how you got the answer nor how there are no other answers nor what was wrong with their answer.

Comment: OK, I have fixed my answer now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(x)+\ln(e)=\ln(18)$, so $\ln(x)=\ln(18)-\ln(e) = \ln(\frac{18}{e})$ and it follows that $x=\frac{18}{e}$.

Alternatively: $\ln(x)+\ln(e)=\ln(ex) = \ln(18)$ so $ex=18$ and we get the same solution.